# Can anyone explain this anomaly when creating block and copy in one line?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
void(^block)()  = ^() {double a=0;
}; //works

void(^block)()  = ^() {double a=0;
}.copy //won't works;

void(^block)()  = (^() {double a=0;
}).copy //this one surprisingly works actually

void(^block)()  = ^() {double a=0;
};
block=block.copy //works but 2 lines
```

This questions is out of simple curiosity

Turns out

```
void(^block)()  = (^() {double a=0;
}).copy works.
```

Curiously

`block=block.copy` doesn't work but `block=[block copy]` works. I wonder why

I simply want to define a block and copy it right away. Something like:

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray array].copy;
```

See, no need bracket there.

Also array=array.copy works just fine.

Comment: `copy` is a method, not a property. It's inappropriate to use property syntax for a method call even if it does work in places.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018231/is-it-ok-to-use-dot-syntax-to-call-methods

Comment: well a method that return something and take no parameter is for all practical purpose property.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW2

Comment: @rmaddy: however, using dot syntax for a no-argument method even if it's not a property has been allowed for as long as I can remember

Comment: From time immemorial as far as I can remember.

Comment: Use dot notation when it’s declared a property. Use regular method syntax when it’s declared a method (e.g. older classes like `-[NSCache setName:]` and `-[NSCache name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the confusion indeed stems from using dot notation where you shouldn’t.

```
void(^block)() = ^ {double a=0;}.copy // does not work
```

This doesn’t compile because the `.copy` is interpreted as accessing a struct field of that name. Thus the Xcode compile error: "Member reference base type … is not a structure or union". (Code snippet spacing edited to demonstrate this.)

Now consider your bracketed alternative:

```
void(^block)() = (^{double a=0;}).copy //this one surprisingly works actually
```

Not so surprising that this works when you consider that the compiler now understands your intentions – thanks to the brackets.